# Excel: Is there a way to change the "Group Total" label in a subtotal row?

Tags: excel, vba, subtotal

I am looking for a way to change the label of a subtotal label to just say total instead of *group* total.

So instead of this:

```
Group    Value
A        100
A        200
A Total  300
```

I get this:

```
Group    Value
A        100
A        200
Total    300
```

Comment: how did you get the "A Total" in the first place?  Is it a pivot table, a formula, or something else?

Comment: this is using the subtotal function in excel, =SUBTOTAL(9,[RANGE])

Comment: subtotal gets the 300, but how are you generating the "Total" text? I'm not sure what your question is, can't you just change the value of that cell to read "A Total"?

Comment: Ok, to clarify... I am really using the Subtotal function in VBA and effectively the Subtotal function under Data>Outline>Subtotal. This will change my "on change" cell to read "[GROUP] Total," but I want it to just say Total.

I can change them yes, but I would like for there to be a way to just do it without post-formatting as I have hundreds of subtotal rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a quick macro to change it.  Assume that the subtotal formulas are in column B (b2:b8 in my example, easy to change), and the "group total" titles are in column A, then this should work:

```
Dim mycell As Range

For Each mycell In Range("B2:B8"):
    If Mid(mycell.Formula, 1, 9) = "=SUBTOTAL" Then
        mycell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Total"
    End If
Next mycell
```